# Multiple user models in Django inherited from AbstractBaseUser

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I have a "legacy" database with different tables for different user types (admins and customers). They have nothing in common. I need to implement both models in the Django project, users need to log in to the client pages, admins to the admin pages (not django admin).

How to solve this deal?
Basically, I have an idea to run two application instances with different config values `AUTH_USER_MODEL` but it looks not the best idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not move the user account info like username password and name to django user and add extra role info to the role table linked by foreign key.

Comment: This is not possible because this database still used and managed by ASP application, but I need to create some additional functions and client front side using Django.

Comment: But while you are doing the migration you can as he did similar thing while migrating from ASP with MS SQL to Django with MySQL

Comment: ASP app still up and use this MySQL database, I added models into the django app with unmanaged flag. This is not option to change database structure.